# Jump to function use, go forward/back a view, in python

Tags: visual-studio, python-3.x, pycharm, spyder

After using C# and visual studio for a while, I find that being able to pull up a list of everywhere the function is used and the definition is extremely useful. It works the same for classes and other references. I also like being able to jump forward and back to previous views.

Is there an equivalent of this in the python world?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a Python IDE (integrated development environment).  This stack overflow question can help you out: [What IDE to use for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python)

Personally, I've used PyDev in the past.